# redirect output from rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I have a bash script to install postgresql
part of the script contains this command

rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm

i need to direct ALL the output generated by this rpm command into a log file FROM
within my bash script
I have tried this

rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm
 >> install.log

however this doesnt stop the following output appearing within my puTTy session

        `package pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5.noarch is already installed

        package postgresql91-libs-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 is already installed

        package postgresql91-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 is already installed

        package postgresql91-server-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 is already installed`

how do i redirect all output into my .log file?

Comment: so you run command like `rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm >> install.log` in one line?

Comment: Running that in one line should put all output to install.log

Comment: yes its all on a single line. do i need to add 2>&1 at the end of that single line?

Comment: @Bolli, that command only redirects stdout to the file, stderr is still output in that case. The OP wants `&>`, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only redirecting `stout` to the file. instead you want to redirect `stderr` and `stdout`.

You should just need to do

```
 command &> file.txt
```

You may want to read a bit more on [Bash Redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm &> install.log
```

This should send all output to your log file.